# Stored Procedure in SQl server 2008 to get sum of column of table and call it in controller in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, controller

I am new to SQL- Server 2008

I want to write a stored procedure to get sum of a column in table and display it in a single column.

and I want to call this procedure in my controller of Asp.net Mvc3 and I am using C# language.

I have a table like...

Table Name: `EmployeeInfo`

```
EmployeeName|MoneyGiven
------------------------
001|2000
002|300
003|400
001|200
003|300
002|400
003|100
```

and I want the result as

```
EmployeeName|MoneyGiven
------------------------
001|2200
002|700
003|800
```

How can I do this?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSum
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT EmployeeName, SUM(MoneyGiven)
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY EmployeeName
END
```

In your front end code just execute this sproc and store the resultset into datareader or recordset.